# findViewById(int) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, button

I've encountered another problem.

I have a script that partitially works.  It worked when the entries in my ListView was around 5-10. However, when I added 50 more entries to around 50-60, it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference` when the script is called.

This is the onCreate, in which the eraseButton removes selected lines in a listview from an SQLite database.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


    //SQLite Database
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    //listview

    final ListView questionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionList);
    final Cursor cursor = db.getData();
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[] { DatabaseHandler.COL_QUESTION }, new int[] { R.id.checkedTextView1 },0);
    assert questionList != null;
    questionList.setAdapter(adapter);
    questionList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    questionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    //Erasebutton listener
    final Button eraseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eraseButton);
    assert eraseButton != null;
    eraseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //erasebutton onclick
        public void onClick(View eraseButton) {
            SparseBooleanArray checked = questionList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = questionList.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                    //What to do with selected listitems
                    TextView tv = (TextView) questionList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
                    db.removeData(tv.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            checked.clear();
            Cursor newCursor = db.getData();
            adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
        }
    });


    //addbutton listener
    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    assert addButton != null;
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Nextbutton onclick
        public void onClick(View addButton) {
            EditText addText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addText);
            assert addText != null;
            String text = addText.getText().toString();
            if(!text.matches("") && text.startsWith("Jag har aldrig ")) {
                addText.setText("");
                db.insertData(text);
                Cursor newCursor = db.getData();
                adapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Börja din fråga med \"Jag har aldrig\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });


    //Nextbutton listener
    final Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
    assert returnButton != null;
    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Nextbutton onclick
        public void onClick(View returnButton) {
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            Main3Activity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
        }
    });


}
```

The line throwing the error is `TextView tv = (TextView) questionList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);`

Does anyone have any idea on why this occurs? I can still select the top 5-10 items from the list and remove them, but as soon as I select a bottom item in the ListView, application crashes with this error.

Comment: instanciate your TextView before the onClickListener not inside of it

Comment: You should being getting your text from the adapter set on `questionList` and not be using `getChildAt(i)`

Comment: Please add more code to your question for the adapter

Comment: @cricket_007 How can I get the text from a specific row in the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should being getting your text from the adapter set on `questionList` rather than use `getChildAt(i)`.

Try to do something like this

```
 for (int i = questionList.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(i);
     if (checked.get(i)) {
         // Get data from cursor
         String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.COL_QUESTION)); 
         db.removeData(text);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for last comment, it worked like a charm, I only forgot to add `Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(i);` I also changed "cursor" to "c" from your script. Figured you wrote wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I copied from somewhere else. Thanks for pointing that out